# How to render Angular App into external HTML

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

i search a solution to load a external website and replace a html comment with my angular App und render the new html.

For example, I have a page that shows a banner and a footer and in the body Tag it has a comment <!—- htmlbody —->

Now I want load this html and replace the htmlbody comment with my angular app.

Actually I solve it by ServerSideRendering but I don’t want all the limitations of SSR.

Is it possible with „normal“ angular to solve my problem?

Comment: This should be very possible, however, using a comment is a bit tricky as you’ll need to traverse all dom nodes to find it (you can’t select it using querySelector). But once you have a reference to it, you can dynamically create an app-root element in that spot before you boot angular (so you need to do this in main.ts). Should work as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you have a small example for me? I don’t know how I can do it exactly.

Comment: Sorry on my phone. But just basic DOM manipulation should do? AppendChild? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp